# How can I use imported images with setIcon() method in java(netbeans)?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm on a project where I have to display an image on jLabel on the click of a jButton. Now I want to display an image that is already imported into the project (src folder) and I don't want to use the path of the image file inside the .setIcon(path/image.png) method as the path of the image will surely change when I will run the program on an another pc. So is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
JLabel jLabelName = new JLabel();

jLabelName.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PathtoImage));
```

sample:

```
new ImageIcon("C:\\java\button.jpg");
```

Answer (score -1):

Relative Path could resolve your issue.
Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/assets/images/admin.png")).getImage();

Or

this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/assets/images/admin.png")

but remember you should place your assets folder inside the src folder. Otherwise the assets folder is not contained in the program's .jar

Comment: hi, you can also set image form URL

image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecommerce-and-business-icon-set/128/admin.png")));